# Not able to get data from collection backbone on rails

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am making an app using OMDB api. I have define a method 'top_movies' in 'movie_controller' which is rendering json data.

I have defined collection like this:

```
class Fanboy.Collections.Movies extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/movie/top_movies'
```

[Click to see JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEgkk.png)

I fetched the collection in console and getting the objects in this manner.

[Click to see the Image view of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8vFh.png)

I want to display the list on a page. But I am not able to show the list.

**movies_router.js.coffee**

```
class Fanboy.Routers.Movies extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    "": "index"

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Fanboy.Collections.Movies()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
    view = new Fanboy.Views.MoviesIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#movies-container').html(view.render().el)
```

/view/movies_index.js.coffee

```
class Fanboy.Views.MoviesIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['movies/index']

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(movies: @collection))
    this
```

/templates/movies/index.jst.eco

```
<h4>Top movies of all time </h4>

<ul>
  <% for movie in @movies.models : %>
    <li><%= movie.get('Title') %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Here I am able to see h4 tag but not the list of Titles. What I am doing wrong here? Please someone help.

**Update:-** I did some debugging. Since the url defined is coming through Omdb API and the view are loaded asynchronously in backbone. Hence the issue.

So I put setTimeout for few seconds and now I am able to display the list. But this makes the app slower. What can I do now?

Though `@collection.on('reset', @render, this)`should have handled the issue. But why it is not able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `'reset'` use `'sync'`:

```
@collection.on('sync', @render, this)
```

> "sync" (model_or_collection, response, options) — when a model or collection has been successfully synced with the server.

[Backbone.js Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

Comment: Here also click event is not firing. I have defined the event in `view/movies_index.js.coffee`.  The button is inside the `template/movies_index.jst.eco`. Could you tell why?

Comment: you'd have to stick up some code to have a look at, if you want, open a new question

Comment: I have opened a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306398/backbone-click-event-not-firing